# HOW to grep "ohn" in certain column?

Tags: bash, unix, awk, grep, sh

```
Finance    Dean Johnson   FULLVegans       Sandeep Jain
```

For example, I want to grep ohn from column 12 to 26, how can I write?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way by awk

```
awk 'substr($0,12,14)~/ohn/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this command:

```
gawk -v FIELDWIDTHS='11 15' '$2~/ohn/' input.txt
```

---

- `FIELDWIDTHS`: A  whitespace separated list of field widths.  When set, gawk parses the input into fields of fixed width, instead of using the value of the `FS` variable as the field separator.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
 grep -E '^.{11,23}ohn'
```